# Making a Promise resolve only when all 'then's in the chain have been resolved

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, ecmascript-6

I'm under the impression that a chain of Promises returns the last Promise in the chain of 'then's. However, that doesn't seem to be the case when I tested the following:

```
function a() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('1');
            resolve(1);
        }, 1000);
    }).then((num) => {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('2');
            return 2;
        }, 1000);
    });
}

a().then((num) => {
    console.log('a is done running');
    console.log('finally, ', num);
});
```

The code currently outputs

```
1
a is done running
finally,  undefined
2
```

Shouldn't the bottommost fulfilment function run only when all Promises in the chain have completed?

How would I get it to output the following?

```
1
2
a is done running
finally,  2
```

Comment: You want `Promise.All()` i believe : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all - create all your promises and pass them as an array to Promise.All()

Comment: the timeout in the first then does not do what you think. The result of that code would be, as you see, a resolved value of `undefined`

Comment: You are getting undefined because the `return 2` part inside the `setTimeout` actually returns nothing. The arrow function inside the second `then` must return a promise. When you run `a()` that actually is running the promise inside it, but not returning anything.

Comment: @Darren `Promise.all` will run the promises simultaneously. The question appears to want the promises to run in sequence.

Comment: @JuanStiza I have seen some examples returning a value inside a 'then' instead of a promise. Why is it that it does not work here? Is it only if there is an additional 'then' down the chain?

Comment: @CodingIntrigue - ah, gotcha. Thanks for the clarification :) Seems like a pointless use of promises though, no?

Comment: the value returned from `.then` is a Promise. What you need to realise is what you are actually returning in .then ... there is no return statement, you return undefined

Comment: That is correct. I think the thing is that you need to understand that in `foo().then()`, `foo` is an object and `then` is an attribute of that object. If foo is a function and it returns a `Promise` object and it is fullfilled, then that `then` will be run. I `foo` returns undefined for some reason you'll get a `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` Error. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that by actually returning a new promise:

```
function a() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('1');
            resolve(1);
        }, 1000);
    }).then((num) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          setTimeout(function() {
              console.log('2');
              return resolve(2);
          }, 1000);
        })
    });
}

// the "then" here actually comes from the second promise.
a().then((num) => {
    console.log('a is done running');
    console.log('finally, ', num);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just because you dont have a Promise in the first then (the one where you console.log(2))... So it returns nothing and the promise is "instantly" resolved. So it executes "a is done running" etc... and then it logs what was in the timeout.. Hope it helps ;)